# Imaging a 3d array with R

Tags: arrays, r, image, 3d

I have got a question regarding array's visualization in R. There is an image() function which makes a 2d-image based on the matrix that it is received; however, this function are not valid for arrays.

So, how is it possible to make a 3d-image through a 3d-array?

For instance:

```
 y<-matrix(round(runif(144)),nrow = 12,ncol = 12,byrow = TRUE)
 image(y, axes=F)
```

Now how we can make a 3d image if we have:

```
y=array(data=round(runif(12*12*12))+1,dim = c(12,12,12))
```

Regards,

Shapour

Comment: You can use the [rgl package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgl/versions/0.99.16) for this

Comment: I have tried to use different functions in this package but still I do not get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

there is image3d function in misc3d:

```
    library(misc3d)
    library(rgl)

    y=array(data=round(runif(12*12*12))+1,dim = c(12,12,12))
    image3d(y)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It was useful!